# Wordpress plugin not automatic update

Tags: plugins, wordpress-version

Sorry about this if dupplicate topic, but I checked all previous question and didn't see any answer for me.

I'm using Wp 9.1 and have many plugin, recent I didnt see wordpress plugin not check new version. For example, the plugin: XML Generator now is 4.0.6, and my plugin is 4.0.4
But when I check update core, it say: " all plugins are up to date"???

Please help me to fix this?
Thanks in advance.
Andy

Comment: This topic has been handled quite a lot of times. Please check [this search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=plugin+not+updating) of this site

Comment: WordPress 9.1???!!!??? do you mean WordPress 3.9.1?

Comment: Is this over considerable span of time (days) ? Can your installation make other network request (for example fetch RSS feeds in dashboard)?

Answer (score 0):

It must be done in wp-config.php file. There is two ways to accomplish this.

1. Defining a constant or
2. Adding a filter.

lets check WordPress codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates) guideline in "Plugin & Theme Updates via Filter" section. That must fulfill your need.

Let me know if it works!

Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks Ariful Islam Shaon.
I'm add a filter after 
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );

But it's not working.

The core update is ok, but the plgs are not, for example: XML Sitemap still old version.

I've just troubled with the plugins